# re-starting/running/waking up a python thread after it finished

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

As you can see from the code below I have a infinite cycle "while(True)" and I want to re-run a python thread after it has finished but without the need to having a infinite cycle. Assume "real-time"/embedded and it does not allow infinite cycles. It seems like sched library can help but that is attached to timings events and I want to do it on demand after some other event not related to an alarm or timing.

Thanks for your answers.

```
from threading import *
from time import sleep
import signal

fd = open("OutputFile.txt","w")
fd_lock = Lock()
event = Event()

def print_letters(file):
    letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O']

    while(True):
        event.wait()
        
    #    while(True):
        #fd_lock.acquire
        with fd_lock:
            for letter in letters:
                file.write(letter + ", ")
            file.write("\n")
            file.flush()
        
        #fd_lock.acquire

        event.clear()

    return 0

def print_numbers( file):
    numbers = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15']

    while(True):
        event.wait()

    #    while(True):
        #fd_lock.acquire
        with fd_lock:
            for number in numbers:
                file.write(number + ', ')
            file.write("\n")
            file.flush()        
        
        #fd_lock.acquire

        event.clear()

    return 0

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler call signal num',signum)
    if(signum == signal.SIGALRM):
        signal.alarm(1)
        event.set()            

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t_pl = Thread(target=print_letters, args=(fd, ))
    t_pn = Thread(target=print_numbers, args=(fd, ))

    t_pl.start()
    t_pn.start()

    #signal.signal(signal.SIGALARM, handler(signum, frame))
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(1)

    while True:
        #kbd = input("Stop wirting to the file [y/n]")
        #disregard this section of the code
        kbd='n'
        if kbd != 'n' and kbd != 'N':
            signal.raise_signal(signal.SIGKILL)          
        else:
            sleep(5)

    t_pl.join()
    t_pn.join()

    signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: "I want to do it on demand after some other event."  But you also want to run the thread again after it finishes, you don't want to use while(True) within the thread, and you don't want to use a scheduler.  Please clarify your requirements.  Why don't you just start the threads when you receive the signal?

Comment: hello @PaulCornelius thanks for your reply I already did it by calling thread.start() inside def handler(signum, frame): but it marks me an error saying "a thread can only be started once".